# Creating a Public String / Public Variable in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

So I'm trying to get a name from the database, then echo this name using the public string, `@namea`, wherever I choose on the page.

I have found a way of doing it, however it's so hacky and clearly isn't the way to do it.

So here is my code...

```
@code{
public string namea = "";
 
 public string cryptoName()
 {
    var test = db.Get("Names");
    namea = db.name;
    return db.name;
 }
}
```

And the HTML which calls it

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
    <small>@namea</small>
</li>
```

I did think within the `@code` block, you'd be able to just do the following:

```
db.Get("Names");
var namea = db.name;
```

Then reuse `namea` within the HTML... but adding this into @code, not wrapping within cryptoName() just returns [this error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0825?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0825)).

Please note; I know this is extremely basic, but I'm just looking for best practices. Thanks.

Comment: This can be done by setting up class to store the name. Then providing the class as a service in `program.cs` and then Injecting it where needed. Personally I would create a component that just displays the name and Inject the class into that. The component can then be used anywhere.

Comment: @BrianParker, wow. Blazor really is a learning curve coming from WebForms. Any useful links you could share to help with your suggestion?

Comment: Give me a few mins. Ill write a demo.

Comment: It should be noted, I'm getting the value from a query string... then using it to search the database to return the value. `?example=p`. `db.get(p);` 

I'm not sure if this would change the approach

Comment: The `@code` block is not something that gets executed when the page loads, it is a "partial class". This is why you can also do [code-behind](https://devkimchi.com/2021/03/10/blazor-code-behind/#combination-of-partial-class-and-componentbase-inheritance). in a separate file. Because it is a class, you obviously cannot call functions directly. That's why you have [lifecycle methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

Class to store the name:

```
public class SomeConfig
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public event Func<Task> Notify;

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Notify?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Inject the class as a service in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SomeConfig>();
```

In some component say `MainLayout` update the name.

```
@code {
    [Inject]
    private SomeConfig Config { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200); // Simulates an Async database call
        Config.SetName("Brian");
    }
}
```

Then in any component you simply inject the same service and use the name. I created a component just to display the name.

`NameView.razor`

```
@implements IDisposable
@Config.Name
@code {
    [Inject]
    private SomeConfig Config { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => Config.Notify += OnNotify;

    private Task OnNotify() => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose() => Config.Notify -= OnNotify;
}
```

**Usage :**

```
 <small><NameView /></small>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@code` block is not something that gets executed when the page loads, it is a "partial class". This is why you can also do [code-behind](https://devkimchi.com/2021/03/10/blazor-code-behind/#combination-of-partial-class-and-componentbase-inheritance) in a separate file. Because it is a class, you obviously cannot call functions directly. That's why you have [lifecycle methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

I believe that @BrianParker's answer is overkill and may be hard to understand if you are new to Blazor. For your specified problem this is something minified:

`Index.razor`:

```xml
@page "/"

<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
    <small>@name</small>
</li>
```

`Index.razor.cs`: (note that if you name your files like this the solution explorer provides a nice hierarchy)

```cs
// A bunch of using statements

public partial class Index : ComponentBase //Similar to ControllerBase
{
   [Inject]
   private IApiService ApiService { get; set; }

   string name = "";

   public override async Task OnInitializedAsync() //Comes from ComponentBase
   {
      name = await ApiService.GetNameAsync(); //Simulate a long API or DB call

      await base.OnInitializedAsync();
   }
}
```

I prefer using the code-behind approach instead of `@code` because it keeps things organized and IMO complies with SOLID in some way.

Comment: This will not work. The "overkill" you describe was to meet the Async getting of the name. Without this YOUR CODE will NOT work. The screen will never be updated.
> It should be noted, I'm getting the value from a query string... then using it to search the database to return the value.

Comment: @BrianParker Please read the documentation on [component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0). After `OnInitializedAsync()` is finished, the component is automatically re-rendered. "Override this method if you will perform an asynchronous operation and want the component to refresh when that operation is completed." I do not think there is any reason for downvoting.

Comment: Your method has a flaw. If multiple components need the "name" multiple requests are required.

Comment: His question did not mention anything about multiple components, OP was trying to figure out how to write code. You can use cascading parameters or caching in your repository service to avoid multiple requests, but for someone that is just trying to get going that's too much.