# Best place to place code that I need in a page, razor components and in NavMeuu.razor - base class for app

Tags: blazor

I am learning Blazor so I apologize if this sounds basic.  Imagine I have a out the box Blazor Server App from Visual Studio (counter app).  I have a database call (looks up the user in  database and brings back meta data) that I would like to share with all my components as it could be used in several places.  I would only like to make this call once and pass the object around or trickle the object down to other components in the app.  This includes NavMenu.razor which is a Shared item.  I wasnt sure the best place to put such a method or how

In asp.net web forms I would have created a base class for the Master page and exposed the object that way.  But im not totally sure of the best way to do this in Blazor Server.  Any advice woudl be much appreciated

Many thanks in advance

```
I have two services in Startup.cs
```

services.AddScoped();     //This service gets me the current UserName from win Authentication
services.AddSingleton();    //This class takes the Windows user from above class and does a database call

But when I call the 2nd class I get an error saying that the first class is null

```
    [Inject] Core.UserService _UserService { get; set; }

    public CsatUserModel PowerUser { get; set; }

    public CsatUsers()
    {
        string un = _UserService.UserName;
        Task<CsatUserModel> task = GetUserAsync(un);
        PowerUser = task.Result;
    }
```

Comment: You need to look at creating a class that provides this functionality as a service. You add this as a service in `program.cs` and Inject it in any component needed. The service will have to notify changes via events which the components will hook to and update their output as required.

Comment: I did something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647161/1492496

Comment: Hi, thanks ever so much for this its really helpful.  Does it matter in the order that I add the dependency injection... I am assuming they happen in sequence?  I have added my code above - to show how I am calling it

Any idea what im doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Order is only important if your providing and instance and it has dependencies. I normally try and provide via interface for mocking and testing. `services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();`

Comment: Thanks Brian, your a star, really appreciate all your help.  Worked a treat

Comment: As addition to @BrianParker suggestions I would suggest to look into state management strategies for Blazor and pick what suits you case the best. As those strategies also describe where to put what kind of logic. Here is a good article about this. https://jonhilton.net/blazor-state-management/
(MvVM is also a viable option)